# The interface port must be passed an actual interface : system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, register-transfer-level

I have a top level file where I have an instance of an interface. This is the code in my toplevel file

```
LC3_io top_io; // LC3_io is the interface which is defined seperately in my interfaces file.

LC3_test test(top_io); // Passing the interface to my testbench
```

test is the instance of my LC3_test(Testbench).

Now, after passing this interface to my Testbench . I have a separate testbench file where my first line of code is :

```
program automatic LC3_test(LC3_io.TB top_io);
```

I have written some other code in the testbench.

The problem when I am trying to simulate the testbench is :

```
**Fatal: (vsim-3695) DUT_Testing.sv(0) : The interface port 'top_io' must be passed an actual interface.
FATAL ERROR while loading design.
```

I do not understand where the problem could lie. I am compiling all the necessary files using vlog and trying to run/ simulate my testbench using vsim. I have tried removing program and using a module instead for the testbench but the problem persists. Is there anything I am missing here ? Thanks

Comment: It's pretty much accepted practice not to use `program` blocks, even if they exist in the standard.

Comment: Is `LC3_io.TB` a modport?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the types don't match. You're expecting an argument of type `LC3_io.TB` for your program block, but you're passing in an interface of type `LC3_io`. Try changing your code to this:

```
// pass the TB modport from 'top_io'
LC3_test test(top_io.TB);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had solved the problem - I was generating  clock in the testbench instead of the top file and then passing the clock to the testbench and the DUT. Sorry for the really late reply. It seems that having modports in the argument doesn't have any effect though.

Comment: @MojoJojo58 Kind of sounds like a tool bug. Modports and stuff anyway feel like uncharted territory. They sound nice on paper, but a lot of the times they weren't really implemented properly.